# reconstructing line diagrams from subpixel rendering

Tags: image-processing

I wish to interpret potentially monochrome bitmaps which appear to have been antialiased or compressed through JPEGS. Here is an example:

[image]

Although it appears monochrome magnification shows:
[image]

Where have the colours come from? If we assume the original was monochrome (black + white) with sharp edges can we use this information to reconstruct the original (with less loss than simple image analysis)? If so is there a F/OSS library (Java preferred) to do it?

NOTE: I have altered the title because of @duskwuff's answer

Also the non-text seems to be grayscale (as implied by @duskwuff). Is this antialiasing? and can it be reconstructed?

[image]

Comment: The colors are the result of [subpixel rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering). It may be possible to use them to reconstruct the original at up to 3x the original horizontal resolution.

Comment: @duskwuff Very useful. Is there a library for (a) detecting the effect (b) reconstructing the original? Happy to upvote an answer

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it a little more, it's probably not going to be useful, since it looks like it's only present on text. (Which is probably just going straight to OCR.)

Comment: @duskwuff I have to reconstruct the lines as well (perhaps using the Canny algorithm). They seem to be subpixelled as well? And even if I do OCR wouldn't it be useful to remove the subpixelling first? I am also planning to enhance the text by aggregating identical characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where do they come from?  The original was most likely not really monochrome.  It is common to use varying shades of grey to help reproduce a straight line.  Zoomed in it may not look the best, but at the intended display scale this makes the pseudo binary image look better.  Did you look at the original to confirm it is really monochrome?

Remember you are looking at a sampled version of the line.  If they sample using linear interpolation (will look like what you have) it looks better then if they had done nearest neighbor (will be strictly monochrome).

If you wish to convert to monochrome you need to threshold the image to make it binary.  Simply loop through each pixel and if the value is <128 make it zero and if it is >=128 make it 255.

Comment: thanks. There is no original - it is a bitmap extracted from a PDF. What confuses me is that the text, but not the lines or circles, have colours. Re your binarization I think I can pass a deconvolution filter over the image before binarization.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust If it is an image from a PDF then  it is no surprise you are seeing what you are.  I'm not sure what you mean by the text having colours, but the circles and lines not.  I see the same effect in all the images you posted.  In less you plan on working on the magnified image, I don't think you have too much to gain from applying a deconvolution or a sharpening filter before binarization.

Comment: I'm not sure what your end game is, but remember the interpolation you are seeing is intentional to make the image better to look at and the text/lines easier to read, converting back to pure binary will probably decrease the perceived quality of the images.

Comment: My endgame is to reconstruct the lines, points and characters (i.e. similar to Optical Character Recognition but with a clearer idea of the final target - monochrome objects). I appreciate that this is non-trivial but there can be a number of heuristics. I am not concerned about the human perception of the images - this is for machines.

Comment: @peter.murray.rust It sounds like straight thresholding should meet your needs.  If you are looking to interpret the image then you can use the hough transform and correlation to create a computer description of the points, lines, and numbers.

Comment: thanks. Actually I have not found Hough very useful - I am currently using the Canny edge detection and fitting lines afterwards. I suspect that it may work in this case - but on a heuristic basis

Comment: @peter.murray.rust Using canny and then fitting lines will work.  You could also use Hough to obtain the line definition and then define endpoints using the canny edge detected images.