# reconstructing line diagrams from JPEGs

Tags: image-processing, jpeg

I wish to recreate characters and graphics primitives from JPEG images. Although the JPEG tranformation is lossy, because the original is (probably) monochrome with well defined primitives it can be largely reconstructed. I would like algorithms or heuristics that could enhance the signal to noise. This is a typical example:

[image]

I have applied the Canny edge detection algorithm and get good recognition of the edges of the numbers but this also includes noise:

[image]

I have tried to eliminate the background by binning into black and white at half-intensity which gives:

[image]

with the background removed but poorer outlines.

I can try heuristic solutions but this will take time and be arbitrary and so I would like to know if there are already solutions.

NOTE: A [similar but not duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16242731/reconstructing-line-diagrams-from-subpixel-rendering) question relates to subpixel rendering which requires a completely different approach.

Comment: As a general point, I would do as much noise reduction as possible *before* Canny - I'll look more closely in the meantime...

Comment: @Roger Agreed. Also I am working on a magnified image and that also helps. But I am impressed with canny in this type of problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, not strictly an answer, but just showing an example of what I mean by removing noise before edge detection.

The following sequence uses your original image and by using ImageJ, with auto-selection of parameters, I did the following:

1. Converted RGB original to 8-bit greyscale (removed most background).
2. Auto-threshold of greyscale equivalent.
3. Convert to binary.
4. Trace outline and invert result.

Maybe this would be a better starting point - the sequence below shows your original, the output from step 2 and the output from step 4:

[image: Example processing sequence]

Comment: great! Note that as I know what I am looking for (digits, subset of ANSI chars, and straight lines) heuristics will work well from now on. Glad to know ImageJ works - reluctant to bundle it into my stuff if can be avoided because of the size. May create a simple auto thresholding myself.

Comment: No problem - nice thing about ImageJ is that it's open source, so you can easily see how its algorithms are implemented.

Comment: and all my stuff is likewise OSS. My plan is to read scientific and technical papers from PDF. I can do most of the text and figures with embedded PS - this is the next phase - images.

Comment: Intrigued - is this like OCR on embedded images in PDFs then? Do you have a link so I can appease my curiosity?

Comment: Yes. http://bitbucket.org/petermr/svg2xml-dev. I'll tweak the README.txt. The idea is to read the whole scientific literature from PDF and make it semantic. It's MUCH easier than most OCR as everything is born digital, everything is aligned, monochrome, etc. Our first target is extracting biodiversity trees-of-life. We welcome volunteers :-)

Comment: Excellent thanks - I'll take a look. I see from your profile your in Cambridge too, not far from me (Carl Zeiss in Coldhams Lane).

Comment: Love to meet - email is <SOsig>@g...lemail.com